# ArcGIS Online: Sharing a private map

Tags: arcgis-online

I want to share a map I've made with ArcGIS Online. I cannot make the map public since it contains sensitive material that should only be seen by me and a couple of co-workers.

The problem is that I only seem to be able to either make the map public (for *everyone*) or keep it completely private so that only I can access it when I'm logged in. What I want to do is to be able to share a link so that only people who have the link can access the map (without needing to log in). Is this possible? (I know this to be an option when using e.g. Google maps.)

I am using the free version of ArcGIS Online so if the solution requires the paid version, let me know.

Comment: Create a group, invite users, share map with this group only

Comment: I would prefer a solution where my co-workers don't need accounts. But I will look into this if there isn't a solution like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is not an option to share a secure map through just a link.