# Private Link to ArcGIS Online Web App

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I know that this question has been asked before, but not recently. Is there a way to have a web app that's private but only view-able to others through a link? Similar to the way an unlisted YouTube video works.

EDIT: As suggested in the comments, here is the link to the same question but asked a few years prior: [ArcGIS Online: Sharing a private map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184972/arcgis-online-sharing-a-private-map)

I am simply asking if there are any advancements in this area.

Comment: If this is a near duplicate, you should certainly include the URL.

Comment: having a similar issue, this may or may not be implemented by esri as the group (named user) requires additional licensing why would esri make a private shareable url link without licensing? (they may go via consuming more credits if the private link is viewed..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this GeoNet [thread](https://community.esri.com/ideas/11655-client-facing-password-for-shared-apps) it looks like a very similar idea was proposed (and well recieved) in December 2015. However, if you take a look at the comment history and their respective dates it seems like this feature has not been implemented yet.

Comment: ok thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 1):

It is still not possible to share maps privately without an ArcGIS Online subscription. However, Esri has introduced new user types which gives you greater control over user access and privileges: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/roles.htm

This means you could add a new user with view only privileges. They can be added to private groups so that they can view privately shared apps, maps and data without the ability to edit any of the items.

Answer (score 0):

A way to implement this would be to deploy ESRI's proxy server (https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy). You could keep your app secured, and the proxy would take care of the authentication when a specific link is accessed. This could be some kind of short URL link to obscure things.

This might not be acceptable under your terms of service for ArcGIS Online, though, since you'd be circumventing the named user model.