# Using ArcGIS Online for public-facing site, while keeping source datasets private?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online

I would like to build a public-facing map using the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API, which will display datasets stored in ArcGIS Online.

ArcGIS Online seems to work on the premise that all users have a [Named User](https://www.esri.com/en-co/store/arcgis-online/user-types) account, and will be signing in to their Named User account before accessing any secure content from ArcGIS Online.

This works well for an organisation, but is less suitable for a public-facing map which doesn't require users to log in.

If the map is to be accessible without requiring the users to log in, then the datasets must be shared with Everyone on ArcGIS Online, which means that any ArcGIS Online user has access to the source datasets.

*Is there an option for creating a public-facing map which doesn't require users to log in to ArcGIS Online, without requiring that the source datasets be shared with Everyone in ArcGIS Online?*

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184972/arcgis-online-sharing-a-private-map?rq=1 is similar but not identical. I'm not trying to keep the map private, but rather keep the source datasets inaccessible to Everyone on ArcGIS Online, but accessible when seen in the map front-end

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question - you're saying you any public internet user to be able to see the map and data, but also not be able to see/download the data?

Comment: @GavinR believe so but the way ArcGIS Online is set up it has to be either public or locked down (organisation only) with named user accounts (expensive). I view it as if it is available via http/https then it will always exposes the data (or parts of it).

Comment: Imagine a site like Hotels.com or whatever which has a map that everyone should be able to see. They don't want any random ArcGIS Online user to be able to find the raw data in AGOL, and easily add it to a new AGOL web map. Granted, a savvy user could get to the data using AJAX calls, but that's better than serving it on a plate in AGOL!

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is definitely possible. I've used apps created by another organisation and been able to see/query the data through the app, but not been able to view or open the data in my own map. Although I can see the item when I search for it, it throws an error when I try to open in map view. I'm not sure how this is done, but I think it requires ArcGIS Enterprise.

Comment: Thanks Anneka. I guess this means that an ArcGIS Enterprise / Portal for ArcGIS is required, meaning that this is *not* supported in ArcGIS Online?

Comment: Not supported with an ArcGIS Online subscription alone as you can't control the sharing settings of ArcGIS online hosted feature services in that way. If you host the data on your own server, as an ArcGIS REST service, then I believe you can have a lot more control when you share to ArcGIS online.